# Make a font function that does not leak with fontspec/xelatex

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I am trying to make a function \noteunic with fontspec and xelatex that allows me to write with a unicode font for a limited section of the text only. But when I write this, the font leaks outsite the domain it is supposed to be limited to.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{fontspec} % 
\newfontfamily\noteunic[BoldFont=meiryob.ttc]{meiryo.ttc}
\newcommand\textunic[1]{\noteunic {#1}}

\begin{document}
Main font \\
\noteunic{Something} \\
Not main font
\end{document}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Did you mean to put `\textunic` in the body of the document?

Comment: Don't use `inputenc` if you are compiling with XeLaTeX. Also, use `\DeclareTextFontCommand` rather than `\newcommand`. But none of this is the issue here: @Thruston already identified that.

Comment: I used \DeclareTextFontCommand{\textunic}{\noteunic} instead, but no idea what different does it make. I kind of feel stupid now, but yes the problem was that I have not been using the same function. Thanks Thruston.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code

```
\newfontfamily\noteunic[BoldFont=meiryob.ttc]{meiryo.ttc}
```

defines `\noteunic` a *declaration*, that is, a command whose effect ends only with the group which the command appears in. Not as a command with an argument; the same holds for `\bfseries`, \itshape`,`\large` and the like.

So if you type

```
\noteunic{Abc}
```

you're not saying that only `Abc` should be printed in the `meiryo` font, but “start using `meiryo` from this point on”. However, an end of group will turn off the font selection. Thus the code should be

```
{\notenuic Abc}
```

and the `}` will effectively turn off the font selection.

In the case above, `Abc` is enclosed in a group, but this group does nothing. With your definition of `\textunic`, the code `\textunic{Abc}` would become `\noteunic{Abc}` because of macro replacement, which causes the “leaking” as seen.

LaTeX provides an elegant way for defining the “argument” version for a font change declaration:

```
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textunic}{\noteunic}
```

and with this in the preamble the code

```
\textunic{Abc}
```

will do the expected thing.